# Cant get UIStepper works on 4.3 Simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How Can i make it work on 4.3 Simulator ? its working perfectly on 5.0

is there a way to make it work ? or its not possible ?

this is the code i`m using

```
- (IBAction)player1stepper:(id)sender {

self.player1score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[(UIStepper *)sender value]] intValue]];
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at the first line of UIStepper class.

```
UIKIT_CLASS_AVAILABLE(5_0) @interface UIStepper : UIControl {
```

UIStepper is available only from IOS5.